# Is it possible to connect to a Postgres DB from SageMaker Data Wrangler?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, data-wrangling, feature-store

I set up a regular Postgres DB in AWS using the [Amazon Relational Database Service (RDS)](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/). I would like to ingest this data using **[data wrangler](https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/data-wrangler/)** for inspection and further processing.

Is this possible? I only see S3, Athena, Redshift and SnowFlake as the data ingestion options. Does this mean I must move the data from Postgresql to one of these 4 options before I can use Data Wrangler?

If it's not possible through data wrangler, can I connect to my Postgres through a Jupyter notebook, using a connection string or some kind of option like this? I'm looking to use the data for the SageMaker Feature Store.

Answer (score 1):

Using Amazon RDS with DataWrangler is not possible (yet).

That said, you can connect to Postgres in Jupyter using Python and then use the Feature Store API to ingest data and use it for subsequent tasks.

Source: AWS employee

Comment: There may also be the option of using the JDBC connector alongside Athena to run queries against Postgres directly, but this seems to complicate things. Seems like moving data from Postgres to S3 is the best option, although this does duplicate data.